# Command 'hadoop jar' Doesn't Take -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8?

Tags: hadoop

Consider the following main class for map-reduce job:

```
public class App extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ToolRunner.run(new App(), args);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().toString());
        return 0;
    }

}
```

When using in interactive shell, it outputs 'UTF-8'. When using in crontab, it's 'US-ASCII'.

But use 'java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar xxx.jar', it works fine in crontab. However, 'hadoop jar' command doesn't take this parameter:

```
hadoop jar xxx.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

In crontab, it still outputs US-ASCII.

One solution is export a LC_ALL env:

```
0 * * * * (export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; hadoop jar xxx.jar)
```

Is there another way?

**Update**

Another env I find useful is HADOOP_OPTS:

```
0 * * * * (export HADOOP_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"; hadoop jar xxx.jar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable `HADOOP_OPTS` to contain args like this. They are really arguments to `java`. See the `bin/hadoop` script; it will add these to the `java` command.

Comment: You just changed your answer based on my update and comment. In your previous answer you suggests "hadoop -D... jar", which you don't even test it. I don't think it's a graceful thing to do.

Comment: I don't understand. You were correct, my previous answer was wrong. (It works if you invoke a Hadoop client via `java`, but that's not what you're asking.) So I posted a new answer that does work. What's the problem here @Jerry?

Comment: Test before you answer, that's all I'm asking.

Comment: Its a weird attitude Jerry. I apologize for making a mistake but if you want people to guarantee their answers you won't get much help here. Burden is still on you to solve your problem.

Comment: You're right. After all I've learnt something from your previous answer, because it drove me to read the source code of 'hadoop' command to verify. I should be more open-minded.

Answer (score 0):

We found that the problem was that the mapper java processes didn't have **-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8** . We had to add that to "mapreduce.map.java.opts". Same for "mapreduce.reduce.java.opts".

You can do it in the XML config files, as well as in Java like:

```
config.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts","-Xmx1843M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8");
```

See http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html for config details.